# Strip HTML tags to get strings in python

Tags: python, html, html-parsing, beautifulsoup, strip

I tried to get some strings from an HTML file with BeautifulSoup and everytime I work with it I get partial results.

I want to get the strings in every li element/tag. So far I've been able to get everything in ul like this.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
page = open("page.html")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
source = soup.select(".sidebar li")
```

And what I get is this:

```
[<li class="first">
        Def Leppard -  Make Love Like A Man<span>Live</span> </li>, <li>
        Inxs - Never Tear Us Apart        </li>, <li>
        Gary Moore - Over The Hills And Far Away        </li>, <li>
        Linkin Park -  Numb        </li>, <li>
        Vita De Vie -  Basul Si Cu Toba Mare        </li>, <li>
        Nazareth - Love Hurts        </li>, <li>
        U2 - I Still Haven't Found What I'm L        </li>, <li>
        Blink 182 -  All The Small Things        </li>, <li>
        Scorpions -  Wind Of Change        </li>, <li>
        Iggy Pop - The Passenger        </li>]
```

I want to get only the strings from this.

Comment: Have you solved the issue? Did any of the answer help? If yes, choose one and accept. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use beautiful soups - .strings method.

```
for string in soup.stripped_strings:
print(repr(string))
```

from the docs:

> If there’s more than one thing inside a tag, you can still look at
>   just the strings. Use the .strings generator:

or

> These strings tend to have a lot of extra whitespace, which you can
>   remove by using the .stripped_strings generator instead:

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over results and get the value of `text` attribute:

```
for element in soup.select(".sidebar li"):
    print element.text
```

Example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


data = """
<body>
    <ul>
        <li class="first">Def Leppard -  Make Love Like A Man<span>Live</span> </li>
        <li>Inxs - Never Tear Us Apart        </li>
    </ul>
</body>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
for element in soup.select('li'):
    print element.text
```

prints:

```
Def Leppard -  Make Love Like A ManLive 
Inxs - Never Tear Us Apart
```

Comment: This works pretty fine, but on the first line I also have <span>Live</span> which I'd like to get rid of.

Comment: @cbomb `text` can handle this and extracts the text from all nested tags, see the example I've provided. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This example from the [documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html#Generators) gives a very nice one liner.

```
''.join(BeautifulSoup(source).findAll(text=True))
```